# Append a row to pandas dataframe for select columns only

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to append a new row to pandas DataFrame, but only populate select columns. In the code below, I subset the columns list I'd like to populate and assign a list of values.

```
import pandas as pd

sampleDF = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Tenant','Industry','Square Footage'])

sampleDF = sampleDF.iloc[sampleDF.tail(1).index.item(), ['Tenant', 'Industry']] = ['DE Shaw', 'Finance']
```

The above code doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the append() method by inserting a dictionary. Does this help ?

```
sampleDF = sampleDF.append({'Tenant': 'De Shaw', 'Industry': 'Finance'}, ignore_index = True)
```

Comment: I have the values to be assigned stored in a list. Ideally, would like to assign a list to the columns.

Comment: If you have more data, are they ordered ? If yes, I think the fastest option would be to convert your list into a dictionary and use the method I propose above.

Comment: It's just a list of values that is returned by the function. I have several columns and mapping key - value pairs would add to the complexity.